# Conflict with the foreign key constraint while populating a junction table in a M:N relationship

Tags: sql-server, database

I have a M:N relationship between two tables called Students and Courses... this relationship is called Enrollment.  I am using SQL Server management studio to populate the enrollment junction table with students who have enrolled in courses.  I keep getting the error `The INSERT statement conflicted with the FOREIGN KEY constraint "Enrolled In". The conflict occurred in database "midterm_project", table "dbo.Students", column 'studentId'.`  What does this mean?

Here is my query:

```
INSERT INTO [dbo].[Enrollment] (studentId, courseId, semesterId)
                        VALUES(1, 1, 4),
                              (2, 1, 4),
                              (3, 1, 4),
                              (4, 1, 4),
                              (5, 1, 4),
                              (6, 1, 4),
                              (7, 1, 4),
                              (8, 1, 4),
                              (9, 1, 4),
                              (10, 1, 4);
```

Here is my database model:
[image]

### Update:

I forgot that I had to delete my Students table and I created it but never populated the students table.  So now I have populated the students table but I am now getting the error below when I populate the enrollment table using the same query above.

```
The INSERT statement conflicted with the FOREIGN KEY constraint "Has Scores". The conflict occurred in database "midterm_project", table "dbo.Assignments", column 'enrollmentId'.
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: EnrollmentId is unique or not? If it is not a unique key, assignment has problem. If yes, enrollment dont need four PK.

Comment: From your diagram, your enrollment id must come from Assignments table. See my update below.

Answer (score 1):

As your enrollment table is weak entity of assignments, you cannot insert the records to enrollment before assignments.
Based on your goals, the diagram I designed as below:
[image]

You can insert a enrollment before insert assignmentsDetail(assignments). If you want one enrollment contains more than one assignment, you must have a id for identify ,as enrollmentId is not unique when you have more than one assignments.

Comment: Wait, so I have to add assignments BEFORE they can enroll in a course?

Comment: Does my design restrict adding enrollment before adding assignments?  If not, that doesn't make sense... in real life, a student can't submit an assignment to be graded unless they're enrolled in a course.  if my design does restrict adding enrollments before adding assignments, how can I change this?

Comment: Change the Assignments be a weak entity to enrollment. It can achieve your goal.

Comment: I feel like you are misunderstanding the purpose of the assignments table.  It is supposed to represent the work that students submit and these are used to calculate a student's grade. assignmentId, enrollmentId, assignmentName, pointsPossible, and pointsEarned should all be in the same table.  Enrolled students can have many assignments but an assignment can only have one enrolled student.

Comment: @ShoeLace1291 Enrollment<-->Assignment reference is reversed on your diagram. @Loser fixed it and now many `Assignments` can be linked to single `Enrollment`. And you should avoid including many columns in primary key. Especially if one of them is an `identity` column - combination of columns becomes senseless in terms of uniqueness.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you're adding a studentid that doesn't exist in the Students table.